# Converting Date/Month into written form kdb

Tags: kdb

Looking to convert the weekend column below from the date into the written form in KDB/Q

```
t:flip (`contra`weekend`PnL)!(4#`abc;("2020.01.10";"2020.02.17";"2020.03.24";"2020.03.31");-222j, 844j, 1897j, 947j)
```

Result should update to

2020.01.10 - Jan-10

2020.02.17 - Feb-17

2020.03.24 - Mar 24

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

The following code fragement should help

```
monthDay:{ ("Jan"; "Feb"; "Mar"; "Apr"; "May"; "Jun"; "Jul";
            "Aug"; "Sep"; "Oct"; "Nov"; "Dec")[(`mm$x)-1],'"-",'string `dd$x:"D"$x }

update weekend:(weekend,'" - ",/:monthDay weekend) from `t
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
q)show m:("Jan";"Feb";"Mar")
"Jan"
"Feb"
"Mar"
q)exec {" - "sv/:flip(x;"-"sv'flip(m mod["m"$"D"$x;12];x[;8 9]))}weekend from t

"2020.01.10 - Jan-10"
"2020.02.17 - Feb-17"
"2020.03.24 - Mar-24"
"2020.03.31 - Mar-31"
```

or if the column needs to remain in the table

```
q)update {" - "sv/:flip(x;"-"sv'flip(m mod["m"$"D"$x;12];x[;8 9]))}weekend from t

contra weekend               PnL
---------------------------------
abc    "2020.01.10 - Jan-10" -222
abc    "2020.02.17 - Feb-17" 844
abc    "2020.03.24 - Mar-24" 1897
abc    "2020.03.31 - Mar-31" 947
```

When it comes to string manipulation in KDB, `vs` (vector from scalar) and its inverse `sv` (scalar from vector) are usually very useful
In the above, first create a list of possible months `m` (I've done 3 to start with)
Next, inside a lambda for brevity's sake, can isolate the day with indexing
Then find the correct month using a combination of casting and the built-in `mod` operator to index into the list of months
Use `sv` to join these lists with a "-" and repeat the process again to join on our initial `weekend` column (this time with " - ")

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the date parsing library available as part of Kx Developer: https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries/date-parser/#printing-dates

This lib provides a number of utilities for parsing dates & times from strings, and formatting them as strings from kdb+ datatypes

Once set up, usage is like so (first few commands are setting up the env for the libraries to work & loading them in a q session - this could also be done with `\l`):

```
jonny@kodiak ~ $ source ~/developer/config/config.profile
jonny@kodiak ~ $ export AXLIBRARIES_HOME=~/developer/
jonny@kodiak ~ $ q $AXLIBRARIES_HOME/ws/axruntimecore.q_ 
KDB+ 3.6 2018.12.06 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
l64/ 4(16)core 7360MB jonny kodiak 127.0.1.1 EXPIRE 2020.06.04 jonathon.mcmurray@aquaq.co.uk KOD #4165225

q)t:flip (`contra`weekend`PnL)!(4#`abc;("2020.01.10";"2020.02.17";"2020.03.24";"2020.03.31");-222j, 844j, 1897j, 947j)
q)update .qdate.print["%b-%d";"D"$weekend] from t
contra weekend  PnL 
--------------------
abc    "Jan-10" -222
abc    "Feb-17" 844 
abc    "Mar-24" 1897
abc    "Mar-31" 947 
q)
```

Note that I had to parse the string dates in your example table to kdb+ dates with `"D"$` as the qdate lib expects kdb+ date/time types.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would prefer Igor's method, it may be useful for you to know that system commands can be used from q console which  may offer you more flexibility in picking desired format. Can be used for example in this case:

```
conv:{"-"^6#4_first system"date -d ", "/" sv "." vs x}
update conv'[weekend] from t
```

edit:
For your exact output:
`update (weekend,'" - ",/: conv'[weekend]) from t`

Comment: Please don't forget that `date` will be executed *in the shell* for each row in `t` which might be very, very slow even for a small table.

Comment: Yep, this is why I prefer your way :)